# density of holomorphic functions in vertical strips

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Define H(a) to be the space of holomorphic functions $f(z)$ on $S_a:=\{z:|\Re z| < a\}$ with
$$ ||f||^2_a:=\int_{S_a} |f(x+iy)|^2 (1+|x+iy|)^{100} dx \, dy < \infty. $$
Two questions:

1. Is H(2) dense in H(1)?
2. Are the entire functions dense in H(1)?

Is there a nice kernel to convolve things with?

This occurs in the following form:  When building an equality of integral transforms, I need to use holomorphy of the test function out to some large domain (wide vertical strip), but the final equality converges absolutely even when the test function is holomorphic on a much smaller domain.  I want to know if I can relax the assumptions on the test function.  (Awfully sure the answer is yes, but why?)

One note:  I mean the natural inclusion of H(2) into H(1), so no composing with conformal maps.

Comment: The $|x+iy|^{100}$ is rather curious... May I ask why are you interested in this question?

Comment: Ya.  You don't gain any functions with that condition:  you only lose them.  So you are looking at the subspace of the full Bergman space of the strips which have a zero of order $50$ at the origin.  Computing these Bergman spaces explicitly shouldn't be too hard because you can actually compute the Riemann map to the disk.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Ah, did not mean to introduce a zero, corrected.

Comment: $H(a)$ is still the same as all functions $f$ for which $(z+2a)^{50}f(z)$ is in the unweighted Bergman space, so the weight doesn't seem to have much of an effect.

Comment: Yes.  Does that help any?

Comment: @JackButtcane: Not sure, but it might give a sufficiently explicit description of $H(a)$ or of reproducing kernels (I think this is also what Steve hinted at in his comment above).

Comment: @ChristianRemling:  I'm really after something more general like H(b) dense in H(a) for b>a, and it seems like conformally mapping to the disk to use the basis there is always going to give you something like $h \circ g$ close to $f$ where $g$ is a composition of conformal maps.  Anyways, I think I probably answered my own question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible I'm over-thinking this:
If $f \in H(1)$, let
$$ f_\delta(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\delta}} \int_{(0)} f(w) \exp ((w-z)^2/\delta) dw, $$
then
$$ f_\delta(x+iy) = \frac{i\exp (x^2/\delta)}{\sqrt{\pi\delta}} \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(i(t+y)) e^{-2itx/\delta} \exp (-t^2/\delta) dt, $$
so $f_\delta$ is entire (integral converges rapidly for all $z$), and $f \in H(b)$ for all $b>1$, by interchanging integrals in the norm and using
$$ (1+|(x+iy)-it|) \le (1+|t|)(1+|x+iy|). $$
Also, on $S_a$,
$$ f_\delta(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\delta}} \int_{(0)} f(z+w) \exp (w^2/\delta) dw, $$
by contour shifting.
Then $f_\delta \to f$ as $\delta \to 0$, by the usual approximation to the identity argument.

This works if we change the norm to
$$ ||f||^2_a:=\sup_{|\sigma|<a} \int_{-\infty}^\infty |f(\sigma+it)|^2 (1+|t|)^{100} dt. $$